Input delay on Ubuntu 22.04 terminal
I am facing some issues with my terminal that I run bash and fish shell. I followed the accepted answer that was; input delay on Terminal Ubuntu 22.04.4 but the issue was back.
I must close and re-open my terminal to fix the input delay issue.
Any ideas how can I solve this issue permanently?
output of echo "$PS1" | od -bc
0000000 134 133 134 145 135 060 073 134 165 100 134 150 072 040 134 167
          \   [   \   e   ]   0   ;   \   u   @   \   h   :       \   w
0000020 134 141 134 135 044 173 144 145 142 151 141 156 137 143 150 162
          \   a   \   ]   $   {   d   e   b   i   a   n   _   c   h   r
0000040 157 157 164 072 053 050 044 144 145 142 151 141 156 137 143 150
          o   o   t   :   +   (   $   d   e   b   i   a   n   _   c   h
0000060 162 157 157 164 051 175 134 133 134 060 063 063 133 060 061 073
          r   o   o   t   )   }   \   [   \   0   3   3   [   0   1   ;
0000100 063 062 155 134 135 134 165 100 134 150 134 133 134 060 063 063
          3   2   m   \   ]   \   u   @   \   h   \   [   \   0   3   3
0000120 133 060 060 155 134 135 072 134 133 134 060 063 063 133 060 061
          [   0   0   m   \   ]   :   \   [   \   0   3   3   [   0   1
0000140 073 063 064 155 134 135 134 167 134 133 134 060 063 063 133 060
          ;   3   4   m   \   ]   \   w   \   [   \   0   3   3   [   0
0000160 060 155 134 135 134 044 040 012
          0   m   \   ]   \   $      \n
0000170


Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour]. Just for curiosity, please [edit] your Question and show us echo "$PS1" | od -bc. Do not use Add Comment. It's for US to help YOU improve your Question,  not a place for conversation.
